# Can I set separate desktop background slideshows for an extended desktop setup with Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, desktop-customization, slideshow

I have a laptop with Windows 10 connected to two external monitors. The dimensions of my three monitors are each very different -- one is my normal laptop monitor, one is vertical and one is extra wide. Currently I have my desktop backgrounds set to a single slideshow. Each monitor displays a different image, but all images are selected from a single folder. Unfortunately, most images do not display nicely on all three monitors, due to the very different dimensions. Therefore, my current single slideshow setup often results in at least one monitor's background looking bad.

I already know how to select separate static images for desktop background on each monitor, but I cannot figure out how to set different slideshows. If there was a way to set slideshows for each monitor from separate folders, that would be ideal. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tool:
http://dualmonitortool.sourceforge.net/download.html
or
download direct in this link: http://sourceforge.net/project/platformdownload.php?group_id=252267

Wallpaper Changer -> Provider -> Add -> 'Select 1° paste, 2° paste, etc, for each monitor'
[image: Wallpaper Changer -> Provider -> Add -> 'Select 1° paste, 2° paste, etc, for each monitor']

Wallpaper Changer -> General -> 'Change the config. to the way you prefer
[image: Wallpaper Changer -> General -> 'Change the config. to the way you prefer]

Wallpaper Changer -> Properties -> 'Here you can see the order of your monitors (eg in the image: monitor 1 and 2)
[image: Wallpaper Changer -> Properties -> 'Here you can see the order of your monitors (eg in the image: monitor 1 and 2)]